# Area routes being ignored?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have these routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Advertisers",
    "advertisers/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Index", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new string[] { "Portal.Areas.Advertisers.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Root", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Index", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaultsm
    new string[] { "Portal.Controllers" }
);
```

However whenever I go to /advertisers/controller/action/id it is not reading the id parameter... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you take a look at the [Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)

**nuget install**

> PM> Install-Package routedebugger

After you've installed it into your project, put this one line of code inside your application start method, and hit the url you're debugging.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

This will tell you exactly why your routes aren't working as expected.

As for your actual question, is your `Controller` actually called `IndexController`? Because this doesn't seem right to me

```
public class IndexController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

My assumption is that you actually have something like `HomeController` or `AdvertiserController`, and if that's the case you should have something like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "advertisers_default", // Route name
    "advertisers/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{advertiserName}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", 
          action = "Index", 
          advertiserName = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { id = "[0-9]+",
          controller = "[a-zA-Z]+",
          action = "[a-zA-Z]+" }
);
```

and then hit the url http://example.com/advertisers/{id}/{advertiser-name}

Simply said, this url looks wrong to me

> /advertisers/controller/action/{id}
>
> it should be
>   **/advertisers/home/{id}**
>
> or even
>   **/advertisers/home/{id}/{advertiser-name}**

Comment: Thanks the debugger is nice and it seems to allow me to do what I need to do.

Comment: no problem. It's "one of" the best tools for MVC route building for sure.